# PhoneGap 2.7 show activityindicator in status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 2.7 and iOS 6. Whenever I load some data from my server, the activity indicator in the ios status bar doesn't appear. I always thought ios automatically takes care about that. But it seems that there is no command in javascript and the plugins are not working as well.

How do i trigger the ActivityIndicator whenever I request data from the server?

PS:

The plugins NotificationEx and networkActivityIndicator are not working with 2.7
`navigator.notification.activityStart();` and `navigator.notification.activityStop();` is deprecated since 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The core functionality is available in the form of plugin

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NotificationEx

With the readme it's pretty easy to install and get started with the plugin.